# Use custom validator in reactive form

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I created custom validation directive:

```
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors, Validator, ValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";


@Directive({
  selector: '[validator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CIFValidator, multi: true}]
})
export class CIFValidator implements Validator {
  constructor() {}

  public validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | any {
    return null
  }
}
```

I currently use it as attribute, but what should I do if I'd like to use it in reactive form config, like this:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    someField: ['', [Validators.NewValidator]]
});
```

?

Comment: What is the problem with it?

Comment: @yurzui I get error "Property 'CIFValidator' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'."

Comment: Just create `CIFValidator` function  or method and use it.

Comment: @yurzui yeah I know, I could make a method but I was wondering whether I cans use such validation directive in reactive form, I just think it's  possible.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/IOYQk3MTEgn8KeCth6Lm?p=preview or https://plnkr.co/edit/Mgo8xnxjg5bVi6h4bSr2?p=preview